# JTable AutoScrolling like IntelliJ Console

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, autoscroll

I want to add a Scroll To End (Autoscroll) function to a jtable with maximum up to 50 rows.
AutoScroll function should work as IntelliJ Scroll To End.

- Initially there are 0 rows. In several milliseconds (say 100 ms.) a few item (1-5 items) is added to the end of the table. If the table row count reaches to the max (50), the first row will be deleted before the next insertion.
- When user scrolls to the end with mouse dragging or scroll wheel, scroll to end checkbox selected and function will be enabled. From that moment, the scrollpane should be scrolled to the bottom of the table like:

  ```
        scrollRectToVisible(getCellRect(getRowCount() - 1, 0, true));
  ```
- When user changes scrollbar position other than the bottom of viewport by dragging or mouse scroll wheel, scroll to end checkbox will deselected and function will be disabled.
- While scroll to end checkbox is not selected, the table will react to scroll bar movements which are sourced by dragging or mouse wheel. But the viewport should show same data.
- If it is impossible to show same data in the viewport because of deletions of the consequent first rows, the visible first data in the viewport will go to the up.

This is the exact behavior of the IntelliJ console log screen.
I wrote Scroll To End enable functionality (90% percent working).
I could not write Scroll To End disable functionality, I don't know to preserve current viewport as stated above.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
package org.example.table;

import com.bsbls.home.gui.test.GuiTester;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MyTable extends JTable {

    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    boolean autoScroll;
    private Consumer<Boolean> scrollToEndListener;
    private Object lastValue;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public MyTable(int max) {
        this.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        this.setRowHeight(24);
        this.setModel(new MyTableModel(max));
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (autoScroll) {
                    scrollToEnd();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public MyTableModel getTableModel() {

        return (MyTableModel) getModel();
    }

    private void scrollToEnd() {
        scrollRectToVisible(getCellRect(getRowCount() - 1, 0, true));
    }

    public void setScrollToEnd(boolean autoScroll) {
        this.autoScroll = autoScroll;
        if (autoScroll) {
            scrollToEnd();
        }
        if (scrollToEndListener != null) {
            scrollToEndListener.accept(autoScroll);
        }
    }

    public void setScrollToEndListener(Consumer<Boolean> scrollToEndListener) {
        this.scrollToEndListener = scrollToEndListener;
    }


    public JScrollPane wrap() {
        if (scrollPane == null) {
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);
            scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
            JScrollBar scrollBar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(e -> {


                if (e.getValue() + scrollBar.getVisibleAmount() == scrollBar.getMaximum()) {
                    setScrollToEnd(true);
                } else {
                    setScrollToEnd(false);
                }

            });

            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

            scrollPane.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                    if (future != null) {
                        future.cancel(false);
                    }
                    future = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                            System.out.println("Yes");
                            JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
                            Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
                            Dimension extentSize = viewport.getExtentSize();
                            //p.translate(extentSize.width, extentSize.height);
                            int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                            if (rowIndex >= 0) {
                                lastValue = getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                }
            });

            scrollBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                    lastValue = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                    JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
                    Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
                    Dimension extentSize = viewport.getExtentSize();
                    //p.translate(extentSize.width, extentSize.height);
                    int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                    if (rowIndex >= 0) {
                        lastValue = getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    // System.out.println(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    //System.out.println(e);
                }
            });

            getTableModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

                    if (lastValue != null && !autoScroll) {
                        int rowCount = getRowCount();
                        int newIndex = -1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                            Object indexValue = getValueAt(i, 0);
                            if (indexValue == lastValue) {
                                newIndex = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println(lastValue + " " + newIndex);
                        if (newIndex > 1) {
                            scrollRectToVisible(getCellRect(newIndex - 1, 0, true));
                        } else {
                            lastValue = null;
                        }

                    }

                }
            });

        }
        return scrollPane;
    }

    static int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuiTester.test(f -> {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            MyTable table = new MyTable(50);

            MyTableModel model = table.getTableModel();


            Random random = new Random();
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, e -> {
                Data data = new Data();
                data.setName(++counter + "");
                data.setX(random.nextInt());
                data.setY(random.nextInt());
                data.setZ(random.nextInt());
                data.setFlag(random.nextBoolean());
                model.addRow(data.toObjectArray());
            });
            timer.start();


            DataPanel dataPanel = new DataPanel();
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e -> {
                int index = e.getFirstIndex();
                if (index >= 0) {
                    Data data = (Data) table.getValueAt(index, 5);
                    dataPanel.setData(data);

                }

            });

            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Scroll To End");
            table.setScrollToEndListener(flag -> {
                checkBox.setSelected(flag);
            });

            checkBox.addItemListener(e -> {
                table.setScrollToEnd(checkBox.isSelected());
            });

            panel.add(checkBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panel.add(table.wrap(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(dataPanel.getPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
            return panel;
        });
    }
}
```

Table Model

```
package org.example.table;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private int max = -1;

    public MyTableModel() {
        this(-1);

    }

    public MyTableModel(int max) {
        super(new Object[]{
                "Name", "Flag", "X", "Y", "Z", "Data"
        }, 0);
        this.max = max;
    }


    @Override
    public void addRow(Object[] rowData) {
        if (getRowCount() == max) {
            super.removeRow(0);
        }
        super.addRow(rowData);
    }
}
```

Dummy data

```
package org.example.table;

public class Data {

    private String name;
    private boolean flag;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;


    public Object[] toObjectArray() {
        Object[] array = new Object[6];
        array[0] = name;
        array[1] = flag;
        array[2] = x;
        array[3] = y;
        array[4] = z;
        array[5] = this;
        return array;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

DatPanel which is a dummy IntelliJ form:

```
package org.example.table;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DataPanel {
    private JTextField fieldName;
    private JCheckBox flagCheckBox;
    private JTextField fieldX;
    private JTextField fieldY;
    private JTextField fieldZ;
    private JPanel panel;


    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        fieldName.setText(data.getName());
        fieldX.setText(data.getX() + "");
        fieldY.setText(data.getY() + "");
        fieldZ.setText(data.getZ() + " ");
        flagCheckBox.setSelected(data.isFlag());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have added to mouse and mouse wheel listeners, and find the first visible row.
And changed scroll mode to simple or backingstore.

```
   scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
```

In that case I have got a better function.
I am still open for better approaches.

Comment: Maybe [Smart Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/)  will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @camickr. You're a good man and developer. Your approach is simple and efficient than mine. Another question: I think your table (or model) is unbounded. What if it is bounded like at most 50 rows?

Comment: This is a solution for scrolling on any Swing compont, JTable, JList, JTextArea, JPanel. It has nothing to do with controlling the rows in the table. You can use your current approach of overriding the addRow(...) method, or an alternative approach would be to add a TableModelListener to the TableModel. When an event is generated you check the number of rows and if the rows is greater that your maximum, you remove the excess rows.

Comment: No. I have also did it. I asked for how to scroll against such behavior. Think new items are added to the end. The oldest item is removed. Since it is removed, The second item of the visible rectangle, will be first item of the visible rectangle after a new item is added when the table has exceded the bound. I dont want to change the first item of visible rectangle unless it is going to be nearly deleted.